# C-code (class/framework/library) in Objective-C

Tags: c, objective-c, cocoa, libusb

How can I reference a class/framework/library like [libusb](http://www.libusb.org/) in an Objective-C class?

Currently I have tried to initiate an enum/struct-function from the library inside my @interface in my .h-file.
But that doesn't work, apparently. :/
I have it "installed" (it's in /usr/local), and tried adding both the files and as framework. Doesn't help, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chances are that you haven't added `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` to the search paths in your project.  In Xcode, bring up either the project settings or the target settings and look for a section named "Search Paths".  Double-click on "Header Search Paths" and add `/usr/local/include`.  Now, double-click on "Library Search Paths" and add `/usr/local/lib`.  When you rebuild your project, libusb should be available.  You will need to add `#include <libusb.h>` at the top of each source file that uses functionality from that product.

Apple makes a distinction between libraries and frameworks.  A library is what you have now.  There are header files and library (dylib) files that you compile and link against.  They are stored in somewhat global locations, such as `/usr/include`, `/usr/local/include`, and so-forth.  Frameworks are bundles that contains headers, libraries, graphical resources, version information, and more.

Comment: But how can I declare a variable/device in the @implentation ? `static struct libusb_device_handle *device = NULL;` gives the following error: `xpected specifier-qualifier-list before 'static'`

Comment: I believe `libusb_device_handle` is a typedef.  Remove the `struct` from that line and it will likely work as expected.  If the compiler still cannot find the type, you probably don't have the `#include <libusb.h>` at the top of you implementation file.

Comment: I still get the same error. The compiler doesn't complain that the file <libusb-1.0/libusb.h> doesn't exist where as it does with <libusb.h>, so I guess I have it included.

Comment: That's because your compiler is looking at `/usr/local/include` and you need to specify `<libusb-1.0/...>` as the library installed its headers under a subdirectory with that name.

What version of OS X are you compiling on?  Which version of GCC or LLVM are you using?  What do your project settings look like?

Comment: I've added /usr/local/include/libusb-1.0/ to the "Header Search Paths" but still won't work. Any chance of you uploading an example? (That'll probably be faster)

Comment: You should really add `/usr/local/include` to the header search path and add the last level into your include statement as:  `#include <libusb-1.0/libusb.h>`

Since you're the one asking the question, it would be helpful if you upload some source and your project settings, as was already requested.

Comment: I followed your instructions and it worked well. However, there are one more step to make it link: I had to add "-l<library name>" to the "Other Linker Flags" of the project target build options. I've got some other problems because I am using a library of mine but I bet that this issues are not relevanto to these example.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy libusb to your project.
2. Add `#include` lines.